# A word of many meanings

Tags: riddle

Mix me up once and I'm dusty and red.

Mix me up twice and I'll make you tingle.

Mix me up thrice and I'm a group of adult male animals.

Name all three words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> arms

Mix me up once and I'm dusty and red

> Mars

Mix me up twice and I'll make you tingle

> ASMR, Autonomous sensory meridian response

Mix me up thrice and I'm a group of adult male animals

> rams

Comment: Very close.....

Comment: Does this word actually have four anagrams or just three? I'm having trouble finding four words to stand for the word and its three mixes.

Comment: Just three mixes.

Comment: Alright, got it now, I think